# Using reactive cocoa to concisely fetch local data and then update with remote data

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I am trying to implement a RACCommand that can be executed to initiate display of the freshest available data to the UI.

Both sendNext: calls would return data from the local database and a remote server respectively.

Is there are more concise way to achieve the same behaviour?

```
self.testObjects = @[ @"initial" ];

RACCommand *command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    RACSignal *s1 = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [subscriber sendNext:@[@"value1", @"value2"]];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            // Cleanup
        }];
    }];

    RACSignal *s2 = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [subscriber sendNext:@[ @"value1-updated", @"value2" ]];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            // Cleanup
        }];
    }];

    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [s1 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            [subscriber sendNext:x];
        }];

        [s1 subscribeCompleted:^{
            [s2 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
                [subscriber sendNext:x];
            }];
        }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            // Cleanup
        }];
    }];
}];

RACSignal *racSignal = [command.executionSignals switchToLatest];
RAC(self, testObjects) = racSignal;

[[self rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath:@"testObjects" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial observer:self] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *x) {
    RACTupleUnpack(NSArray *values ) = x;
    NSLog(@"values: %@", values);
}];

[command execute:nil];
```

Outputs:

values: (
    initial
)

values: (
    value1,
    value2
)

values: (
    "value1-updated",
    value2
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can do all of your cleanup in the disposables for each of `s1` and `s2` (that is, assuming you don't have any global cleanup that you're not mentioning), you can use the `-[RACSignal concat:]` method to chain these two signals together:

```
RACCommand *command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    RACSignal *s1 = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [subscriber sendNext:@[@"value1", @"value2"]];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            // Cleanup
        }];
    }];

    RACSignal *s2 = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [subscriber sendNext:@[ @"value1-updated", @"value2" ]];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            // Cleanup
        }];
    }];

    return [s1 concat:s2];
}];
```

The `-[RACSignal concat:]` method in this case will create a signal which delivers all values on `s1`, and then when `s1` completes will deliver values on `s2`, until it completes (at which time the returned signal will complete).

Comment: Thanks erik, this does work and also revealed my own confusion about how the RACCommand's executionSignals works with switchToLatest.  I had expected that as the concat signal completed testObjects would be updated only once but this doesn't happen, I assume because executionSignals doesn't complete it just keeps sending the next signal.

Comment: The block passed to `-[RACCommand initWithSignalBlock:]` will get called every time the command is executed. So technically, the concat'd signal *does* only update `testObjects` once, but a new concat'd signal is created every time the command is executed, so the net effect is that `testObjects` gets updated multiple times.